# populate another drop down on selection of first

Tags: php, jquery

I am going to populate a another drop down on selection of first drop down. Implementing this with intermediate php file. I am showing second drop down on basis of Jquery.

Jquery code.

```
$("<select/>", {
class: "selectdoctor",
name: "selectdoctor" + i,
id: "selectdoctor" + i
}).appendTo("#prescriptiondiv").after("<br/>");
```

This dropdown will be shown number of times using for loop. So I can populate value in this on basis of class only.
Second jquery that will send value to phpfile and fetch result using ajax has code.

```
$.post("getdoctorlist.php", {
        childid: childid
    }, function(data) {
    //alert(data);
    $('.selectdoctor').html(data);
    });
```

My phpcode for `getdoctor.php` list has code,

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0);
{
    while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
   echo '<option value="'.$result["pcpkey"].' ">'.$result["pcpfname"].'</option>';  
   }
}
```

**How can I fetch this response(data) in `drop down with classname='selectdoctor'` ?**

Comment: I don't think this would be a good practice... try to do with JSON.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm,

I would personally do something along the lines of as your not familiar with JSON:

```
$('.selectdoctor').change(function(){

     var doctor = jQuery('.selectdoctor.').val();


     jQuery.post("getdoctor.php", { doctor: doctor }, function(data){ jQuery("#prescriptiondiv").html(data); });
```

for the Javascript, then by echoing out in the PHP script the second dropdown will be populated (which I assume would be called 'prescriptiondiv') once the 'change' in the first select menu has been made.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html 
and json is easy to learn try that too. that is just a data-interchange format like xml.