# Populate a drop-down list depending on what is selected from another drop-down list from two variables PHP

Tags: php

I have a question on how to populate a drop-down list depending on the value that is selected in another drop-down list.

I'm working with an MVC pattern and when the view loads, it already brings me two variables with the values I need. What are $tipohardware and $tiposoftware.

So I wouldn't need to call a .php file again to get the data, because it's already loaded.

My static drop-down list is:

```
<select id="producto" class="form-control" required>
<option value="">Seleccionar..</option>
<option value="1">Hardware</option>
<option value="2">Software</option>
</select>
```

And the dynamic drop-down list I want to populate depending on what is selected in the drop-down list "producto" is:

```
<select id="tipoproducto" name="tipoproducto" class="form-control">

</select>
```

I already have two variables that have the data of the tables, "tipo_hardware" and "tipo_software". What are $tipohardware and $tiposoftware.

So, for example, if I select the "Hardware" option in the drop-down list, the second drop-down list should be filled with the data of the variable $tipohardware.

On the other hand, if I select "Software" the drop-down list should be populate with the values of the variable $tiposoftware.

Here's my controller if you needed to.

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use \app\models\Hardware;
use app\models\Software;
use app\models\TipoHardware;
use app\models\TipoSoftware;
use \Controller;
use \Response;

class IngresarProductoController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
    $softwares = Software::all();
    $hardwares = Hardware::all();
    $tiposoftware = TipoSoftware::all();
    $tipohardware = TipoHardware::all();
    Response::render("ingresarProducto", ["hardwares" => $hardwares, 
    "softwares" => $softwares, "tipohardware" => $tipohardware, 
    "tiposoftware" => $tiposoftware]);
    }
}
```

I think I should call a php code in a javascript onchange function like:

```
$("#producto").on("change",function){
   <?php
   foreach($tipohardware as $tipohard) {
   ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $tipohard->idtipo_hardware  ?>"><?php echo 
       $tipohard->nombre_tipo_hardwarecol  ?></option>

   <?php
   }
   ?>
 }

});
```

But I dont know how I can continue with that,

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [populate another drop down on selection of first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388263/populate-another-drop-down-on-selection-of-first)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I don't think it's a duplicate question, that question call a .php and for me it's not necessary to call again because the variables already have the data from the database.

Comment: Then you just need a OnChange event on your producto and have a JavaScript/JQuery function that deletes all the items in tipoproducto and populates it from the appropriate variable.   What have you tried?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Sorry I already add that on the original question, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing frontend script with backend script, which does not work. Backend will build the entire page before the frontend starts doing it's thing. PHP creates the DOM and JavaScript manipulates the DOM after PHP spits it out. That is why your jQuery does not work/update.

For example, if you do this:

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
    var whatever = <?php echo rand() ?>;
    alert('This value is'+whatever);
});
```

It will run the php first so you will end up with the random number off the bat:

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
    var whatever = 3241231;
    alert('This value is'+whatever);
});
```

No matter how many times you click the button element, it will always say `3241231` until you reload the page when PHP will run the `rand()` function at load.

To make it load in real time, you need to create an ajax listener to receive a value from the target, send to the backend PHP, then when that backend page responds, you place the response back into your currently loaded page, altering the DOM.

A simple example would be:

**/index.php**

```
<?php
# Create the back end to listen for your front end ajax
if(!empty($_POST['test'])) {
    # Do your code here to send back.
    $rand = rand();
    die('Ajax done! Here is a random number: '.$rand);
}
?>
<!-- CLICK ELEMENT -->
<div id="button">CLICK</div>
<!-- PLACEMENT ELEMENT -->
<div id="response"></div>

<script>
$(function(){
    // When you click the div
    $('#button').on('click',function(){
        // Fire the ajax to the same page (you may want to do a
        // different page in production). Note, I am referencing a new instance of
        // of index.php in the background and sending $_POST['test'] = true as noted
        // in the data section of the ajax below.
        $.ajax({
            'url': '/index.php',
            'type': 'post',
            // Send the data from the click or whatever
            'data': {
                'test':true
            },
            // If there are no server errors,
            'success': function(response){
                // place the phrase 'Ajax done! Here is a random number: 123124'
                // back into the placement div
                $('#response').text(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

In this example, the random number will change each click of the div. Anyway hope this example was helpful.